# Not counting null values from a linq LEFT OUTER JOIN query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this sql query that does exactly what i want but i need it in linq. It returns a few AVC rows and counts how many PersonAVCPermission that has status 1 linked to it

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Address, COUNT(p.AVCID) AS Count
FROM AVC AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT PersonAVCPermission.AVCId
    FROM PersonAVCPermission
    WHERE PersonAVCPermission.Status = 1
) AS p 
ON a.Id = p.AVCId
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Name, a.Address
```

I have this query in linq and it does the same thing except when there are no PersonAVCPermission it still counts 1

```
var yellows = odc.PersonAVCPermissions.Where(o => o.Status == (int)AVCStatus.Yellow);

var q = from a in odc.AVCs
        from p in yellows.Where(o => o.AVCId == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        group a by new { a.Id, a.Name, a.Address } into agroup
        select new AVCListItem
        {
            Id = agroup.Key.Id,
            Name = agroup.Key.Name,
            Address = agroup.Key.Address,
            Count = agroup.Count(o => o.Id != null)
        };
```

Im guessing that with DefaultIfEmpty() it places null rows in the list that then gets counted so i try to exclude them with (o => o.Id != null) but it still counts everything as at least one

If i dont use DefaultIfEmpty() it skips the rows with count 0 completely

How can i exclude them or am i doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the join, nor the grouping:

```
var q = from a in odc.AVCs
        select new AVCListItem
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Name = a.Name,
            Address = a.Address,
            Count = yellows.Where(o => o.AVCId == a.Id).Count()
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using .Any() and a Let?

```
var yellows = odc.PersonAVCPermissions.Where(o => o.Status == (int)AVCStatus.Yellow);

var q = from a in odc.AVCs
let Y = (from p in yellows.Where(o => o.AVCId == a.Id) select p).Any()
where Y == true
group a by new { a.Id, a.Name, a.Address } into agroup
select new AVCListItem
{
    Id = agroup.Key.Id,
    Name = agroup.Key.Name,
    Address = agroup.Key.Address,
    Count = agroup.Count(o => o.Id != null)
};
```

Comment: Your suggested solution causes the query to only return the AVCs with any PersonAVCPermissions and the count is 1 on all rows

Comment: You sure?  I didn't have source objects and data set to test with but in my test project I put together, I got what I expected to see.  (Whether that's right or not, I'm not sure... I thought I was answering the question correctly.) Oh, well... maybe someone gets value from seeing a "Let" in use.